# How to manage status bar show/hide on nested controller

Tags: ios, swift

I want to hide status bar on the top of iphone. I can add below code on my controller to do that. It works if my parent controller has this code. But what I want is to allow my nested controller to hide the status bar. If I add this code on my nested controller, it works make any effect. How can do it on my nested controller?

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: By nested controller you mean child view controller?

Comment: If you are trying to manage in childviewcontroller, do it in childviewcontroller it will take effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your parent:

Objective-C

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
   if(self.childViewControllers.count > 0) {
     return [self.childViewControllers.lastObject prefersStatusBarHidden];
   } 
   return YES;// or any other default value
}
```

Swift:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
  if (childViewControllers.count > 0) {
     childViewControllers.last?.prefersStatusBarHidden()
  }        
     return true
}
```

In your child VC call `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];` for example in `viewDidLoad`

The goal is to ask child view controller (if any exists) about it's `prefersStatusBarHidden`.

Call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` in child to let the system know that current status bar appearance is invalid and `prefersStatusBarHidden` needs to be called again by the system.

Comment: Couldn't you simply override `childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden` and return `self.childViewControllers.last`. See [UIViewController API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621451-childviewcontrollerforstatusbarh)

Answer (score 3):

As Kymer pointed out the right way to do this is to override `childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden`:

```
 override var childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
    return childViewControllers.last
  }
```

Comment: The ? should be removed.