# iOS hide/show status bar in parent view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, statusbar

I want to hide/show status bar on single tap. I use override function  `prefersstatusbarhidden` and `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` in nested view controllerA and it works well. But I want to move hide/show action code into parent view controller B, if I use in the same way of `prefersstatusbarhidden` and `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` in parent controller, it does not work, the status bar keeps showing, any one know the solution? Thank you!

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828673/how-to-manage-status-bar-show-hide-on-nested-controller

Comment: Actually I have checked this, but the promlem is the opposite to me, he wants to implement in nested view controller but I want to implement in parent view controller

Comment: @newszer did you find a solution?